# Foreign Key with Sequelize not working as expected

Tags: foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I was trying to create an association between two tables and I wanted to add a foreign key.

The two models are User and Companies

`User.associate = (models) => {
    User.belongsTo(models.Companies, { foreignKey: 'Company' });
};`

My expectation of the code above was that a Company ID field gets added in the user table which references the Company ID of the Companies table.

On running the code above, I don't see any additional columns getting created. I tried checking if a foreign key association is created in the DB and that also is missing.

However, if I try to add a column with the same name while keeping the association code, I get a name conflict. This seems to suggest that the association is getting created but I am unable to see it.

Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

**models/company.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Company = sequelize.define('company', {
        company: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true },
    });

    Company.associate = (models) => {
        Company.hasMany(models.user, { as: 'users' });
    };

    Company.sync();

    return Company;
};
```

**models/user.js**

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
        id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
    });

    User.associate = (models) => {
        User.belongsTo(models.company);
    };

    User.beforeCreate((user, _ ) => {
        user.id = uuid();
        return user;
    });

    User.sync();

    return User;
};
```

**models/index.js**

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
// var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
var db        = {};

// if (config.use_env_variable) {
//   var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
// } else {
//   var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
// }

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres:user@localhost:5432/mydb');

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
      var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Your code sample is valid. I just tried and was able to create a field `Company` in the `users` table. Could you share your full model definition as well are your DB config?

Comment: I have added it. I am using sequelize version ^4.41.0.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved.

The issue was with regard to the sequence in which the sync was called. In my original code, I was calling sync inside each model. Even though I added the options `force` and `alter`, I think the foreign keys were not getting added. So, I removed the `sync` code from inside the models, and added it in a separate loop inside `index.js`.

This gave me a new issue. Tables were getting created in an order that is not consistent with the order in which tables should be created for foreign keys to work since tables should pre-exist. I resolved it by manually providing the sequence of `sync` and now I see the columns getting created.

To summarise: model defn -> model association -> model sync in sequence

Thank you for your suggestions, members of SO.

Comment: Or you can just create a migration file for each model and run `sequelize db:migrate` to create tables

Answer (score 1):

Your model is fine! you must remove `sync` from models file , then check migration file for models with foreign key that `foregin key` is there,

**for Migration User :**

```
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            companyId: {
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                references: {
                    model: 'Company',// company migration define
                    key: 'id'
                }
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
    }
};
```

for create automate table from index.js and models you must install `sequelize-cli`

by type `npm install --save sequelize-cli`

then you must run this command for create models table in db

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `foreignKey: 'Company'` you are telling it to associate with a column named `Company`. You typically also want to use singular table names, so `company` with an association of `companies`. By default Sequelize will use the primary key for the association, so you only need to specify `foreignKey` if you want to change it or set other parameters.

```
const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  { /* columns */ },
  { /* options */ }
);
User.associate = (models) => {
    User.belongsTo(models.Company);
};

const Company = sequelize.define(
  'company',
  { /* columns */ },
  { /* options */ }
);
Company.associate = (models) => {
    Company.hasMany(models.User, { as: 'users' });
};
```

This will create the following tables `Company (id)` and `User (id, company_id)`.

Query all `User` records associated to a single `Company`:

```
const user = await User.findAll({ include: { model: Company } });
/*
user = {
  id: 1,
  company_id: 1,
  company: {
    id: 1,
  },
};
*/
```

Query all `Company` records with multiple associated `User` records via `users`:

```
const company = await User.findAll({ include: { model: User, as: 'users' } });
/*
company = {
  id: 1,
  users: [{
    id: 1
    company_id: 1,
  }],
};
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code samples. I have updated the post with what I have done (similar to your code), but I don't see the foreign key appear when I look at the table. I am using sequelize version ^4.41.0

Comment: Are you running `Sequelize.sync()`? The new column won't be automatically created...

Comment: Yes, I am calling the `sync()` function. I thought it would create the new column. What should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `associate` method is not getting called, and therefore, your association does not get created. Keep in mind that `associate` is not a built-in Sequelize method, but it is just a pattern used by the community. (More info on [this thread](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4578))

There are various approaches to handle calling `associate`, here is one example. You have a `models.js` file that handles your association and you initialize that inside your main `app.js` file.

```
// app.js (aka your main application)
const models = require('./models')(sequelize, DataTypes);

// models.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const models = {
        user: require('./userModel')(sequelize, DataTypes),
        company: require('./companyModel')(sequelize, DataTypes)
    };

    Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
        if (models[key] && models[key].associate) {
            models[key].associate(models);
        }
    });
};

// companyModel.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Company = sequelize.define('company', {...});

    Company.associate = (models) => {
        Company.hasMany(models.user, { as: 'users' });
    };

    Company.sync();

    return Company;
};

// userModel.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {...});

    User.sync();

    return User;
};
```

Also, FYI, You probably know this but `sync` should only be used for experimenting or testing, not for a production app.

Comment: If I call `associate` in this way, it fails because the `associate` function is expecting models and we are sending nothing, and thus gets treated as undefined.

Comment: @NikhilBaliga I've updated my answer to include more details

Comment: Thanks for the updated code and the additional note, @mcranston18. However, I am calling the `associate` function. I have updated the query with the `index.js` file and if you notice, I am calling the `associate` function at the end. I had picked this code up as a standard way of doing it. I added `console.log` statements and found that the `associate` function is being called. But the relations are not getting created.